# Changing global properties of figure caption

Tags: environments

I'm just looking for a list of global properties which can be changed for the figure captions, such as changing the font size, font type/family etc.

If anyone knows of them, or has a link to a reputable up-to-date website for LaTeX commands that would be most appreciated.

Comment: You should read the documentation of the `caption` package.

Comment: Have you got a link?

Comment: Depending on your TeX distribution you should be able to access `caption.pdf` on your computer; but there's always http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf

Comment: Ideal. I'm on overleaf and Authorea usually.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities here.  If you are using [`KOMA-Script`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en), you may directly go with:

```
\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily\normalsize\mdseries\slshape}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\upshape}

%% Some playing around with Tables
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}

%% Some playing around with Figures
\KOMAoption{captions}{figuresignature} %Default
```

Or, if using the [`captions`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) package ---as mentioned by egreg---, you can always twerk it with something like this (from the `caption` package documentation):

```
\captionsetup{font=small}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,textfont=it}
```